# INSERT with UNION ALL records from different tables in a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I'm trying to insert budget data into a table from two different tables, and I need the results to be separated by each "group" but I want to also display the total budget for each group at the beginning of the grouped data.

For example:

```
Group 1               Total Budget
G1 Component          Budget
G1 Component          Budget
G1 Component          Budget
Group 2               Total Budget
G2 Component          Budget
G2 Component          Budget
Group 3, etc..
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use `order by` because the results are not in alphabetical order and there is no ID sequence that preserves the order that the users want it in. I did not design the tables that I'm selecting from, nor can I change them, so I have to just work with what I'm given.

Right now my code looks like this, to preserve the order that everything appears in the tables

```
   select [columns] from [table 1] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 1 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 1 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 1] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 2 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 2 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 1] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 3 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 3 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 1] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 4 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 4 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 1] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 5 Name]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] where group = [Hardcoded GROUP 5 Name]
```

There are 5 groups total at the moment.

My concern is that my values for each group are hardcoded.
But this insert is going to take place for each budget that the end users need to calculate, and I don't know if the number of groups will change in the future.

The "table 1" referenced in my code above only contains the 5 groups with the total budget for each one, so **is there a way to loop through the results from this table and make the union for each group?**

Something like this, but I don't know how while loops work in SQL:

```
retrieve group names as results
while results not null
   select [columns] from [table 1] where group = [RESULT]
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] where group = [RESULT]
```

The columns and all are identical for each union, the only difference is the name of the group.

Comment: The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by`. No exception.

Comment: Sorry I had accidentally hit enter before I was done, so order by will not work for me, because I'm not ordering by names or columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I'm not entirely sure. I'm using SSMS to test everything, but it's going to end up in a PHP application in the end, so I'm not really sure how to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I think order by is still the way to go. You will need to do some sub queries.That way you will have the result grouped by the group name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(   
   select [columns] from [table 1] 
   UNION ALL
   select [columns] from [table 2] 
)
ORDER BY [group]
```

As for inserting the total budget in between those groups, it would make for quite an ugly query, it might be easier to just calculate it in your PHP script before you display the data.

Comment: Yeah I've been all over the place on what the best overall design for this will be.

I don't know how much to control using SQL and how much to control using PHP, I just want it to be elegant and efficient.